# Can I get digital signal from antenna input in Samsung smart TV?

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app

I want to write application for Samsung smart TV on Tizen OS which will get signal from antenna and do some processing. So is Tizen SDK supports that?

Comment: What kind of data do you expect to get from the SDK?

Comment: My tv does not support DVB T2 digital standard chanels. I want to write program which will get signal from antenna and decode for getting DVB T2 chanels. Or if you know another solution getting DVB T2 chanels please say about that.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but If your TV doesn't support DVB-T2 you cannot get the Transport Stream from the RF signal to process it via software. T2 has different transmission scheme and modes than DVB-T  so the only way to process the signal by software to get DVB-T2 DTV channels is using a DVB-T2 demodulator

You can buy a T2 SetTopBox and connect by HDMI or if you want a DIY solution you can buy a Pi3 + the DTV hat (https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-tv-hat/) but in any case you will need an external device + your current TV set

EDIT: 
The lower public layer of Tizen [NaCl](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/extension-libraries/nacl/overview) allows you create 'native' binaries and access them from a web app. NaCl can use the native API [pepper](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/extension-libraries/nacl/api-references/pepper-api-references) to access low level resources, but for your specific questions, all of them seems to be AFTER the hardware demux, so these means all that you can get from pepper is already related to DVB-T channels (due the hardware chain is responsible to extract the TS, and to access to DVB-T2 the TV needs a T2 demodulator)

For example the pepper API allows you get data from the [elementary stream](https://developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/tv/pepper_56/c/struct_p_p_b___elementary_stream___samsung__1__1.html)  but these video, audio, data, teletext elementary streams are extracted from the TS

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my question is not about DVB-T and DVB-T2. I just want to write program in tizen platform which will get RF signal from ANT (Antenna) input. So is that possible?